# Beginner with Prolog - Arguments Insufficiently Instantiated

Tags: prolog

Brand new to Prolog. I've played around with variable names and making sure variables have a calculated value, but I must be missing something. Could you all have a look and help me figure out what I'm missing?

```
lgstar(N,Answer)                        :- var(N) -> write('undefined'); lgstaranswer(N,Answer).

lgstaranswer(N1,Answer1)                :- lgstarcompute(N1,Iterations),
                                           var(Answer1) -> Answer1 is Iterations, write(Answer1);
                                           (Answer1 is Iterations -> write('yes'); write('no')).

lgstarcompute(N2,Iterations1)           :- N3 is floor(log10(N2)/log10(2)), write(N2), write(N3),
                                           N3=<1 -> Iterations1 = 1;
                                           lgstarcompute(N3,Iterations2),
                                           Iterations1 is Iterations2+1.
```

You call lgstar() to kick things off. The errors I'm getting look as follows:

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [4] _672 is floor(... / ...)
   [3] lgstarcompute(_738,_740) at  line 7
   [2] lgstarcompute(70000,_796) at  line 9
   [1] lgstaranswer(70000,4) at  line 3
```

### Working Code

Thanks to the accepted answer below, the code works. Please read their explanation. The following is working code for the whole function. Just keep in mind your professors know how to use Google!

```
lgstar(N,Answer)                        :- var(N) -> write('undefined'); lgstaranswer(N,Answer).

lgstaranswer(N1,Answer1)                :- lgstarcompute(N1,Iterations),
                                           ((var(Answer1) -> Answer1 = Iterations);
                                           (Answer1 == Iterations -> write('yes'); write('no'))).

lgstarcompute(N2,Iterations)            :- N3 is floor(log10(N2)/log10(2)),
                                           (N3 =< 1 -> Iterations = 1;
                                           (lgstarcompute(N3,Iterations2), Iterations is Iterations2+1)).
```

Comment: @lurker I can't seem to enable trace on the site I'm using (SWISH), that or the trace is unhelpful. Using write(), I have confirmed that N2 has a value at that point. N3 is instantiated there, but in the body of the conditional, N3 is uninstantiated. Does the value of N3 not carry into the body of the conditional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a common mistake. You need to parenthesize your expressions due to operator precedence.

This is what you have:

```
lgstarcompute(N2,Iterations1)   :- N3 is floor(log10(N2)/log10(2)), write(N2), write(N3),
                                   N3=<1 -> Iterations1 = 1;
                                   lgstarcompute(N3,Iterations2),
                                   Iterations1 is Iterations2+1.
```

If I format that a bit nicer, I get:

```
lgstarcompute(N2, Iterations1) :-
    N3 is floor(log10(N2)/log10(2)),
    write(N2), write(N3),
    N3 =< 1 -> Iterations1 = 1
;
    lgstarcompute(N3, Iterations2),
    Iterations1 is Iterations2+1.
```

In Prolog, at least in SWI Prolog, `,` is higher precendence than `->`, which is higher than `;`. So this is equivalent to:

```
lgstarcompute(N2, Iterations1) :-
    (
        (
            N3 is floor(log10(N2)/log10(2)),
            write(N2), write(N3),
            N3 =< 1 
        ) -> Iterations1 = 1
    )
;
    (
        lgstarcompute(N3, Iterations2),
        Iterations1 is Iterations2+1.
    ).
```

What happens is that when `N3 =< 1` fails, Prolog backtracks all the way back to before `N3 is floor(...)` occurs to reach the most recent choice point and `N3` is no longer instantiated. It then goes to the first query after the `;` which is `lgstarcompute(N3, Iterations2)` with `N3` uninstantiated.

To fix it, you need to group using parentheses:

```
lgstarcompute(N2, Iterations1) :-
    N3 is floor(log10(N2)/log10(2)),
    write(N2), write(N3),
    (    N3 =< 1
    ->   Iterations1 = 1
    ;    lgstarcompute(N3, Iterations2),
         Iterations1 is Iterations2+1
    ).
```

Now when `N3 =< 1` fails, it won't backtrack to the `write(N3)` and all the way back to `N3 is floor(...)`, but rather it will take the conjunction with `N3` still instantiated.

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixed that issue, and applied to the rest of my code, the thing works as intended. I'll post the working code as part of the question.

Comment: @H.Martin glad it worked. I wouldn't post the working code, though. It may confused the question for subsequent readers. :) I'd leave it as-is.

Comment: I put it after my original code and marked it clearly. I find it helpful when I have broken and working code to compare. Thanks again!